# Lower Voltage = Higher Potential?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, potential, conventions

I am doing problems from a textbook and one of the questions asks to determine where the higher potential is.

> (b) Find the potential difference between the points on the axis at and which of these points is at the higher potential?

[Check the question here.](http://faculty.washington.edu/mrdepies/122spring08/hw_soln/Ch23%20ISM.pdf)

Problem 37 is the Question (with the solution) I am trying to comprehend.

I was under the assumption that higher Voltage by  definition meant that there is higher potential.

> Because $V_1 =V_2 + 3.00\,\mathrm{kV}$ , the point at $x = 2.00\mathrm{m}$ is at the higher potential.

In this case $V_1 = V(1) = 6\,\mathrm{kV}$ and $V_2 = V(2) = 3\,\mathrm{kV}$.

Why then is it stated that $V(2)$ is at a higher potential?

Comment: My guess is that it's a typo. I would think that V(1) would be considered to be at higher potential since it's a more positive value and since it is further away from the 0 voltage potential at infinity than the point at V(2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I concur with Sam Weir, typo. $E= \frac {b}{x^2}$ So $\frac {6kv/m}{(1 m)^2} =6\,\mathrm{kV}$ at $1\,\mathrm{m}$ and $\frac {6kv/m}{(2 m)^2} = 1.5\,\mathrm{kV}$ at $2\,\mathrm{m}$

I see $6\,\mathrm{kV}-1.5\,\mathrm{kV}=4.5\,\mathrm{kV}$ with $x = 1$ being higher potential, regardless closer to the positive charge is going to be higher potential.